# add get parameter to laravel's redirect method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I use laravel 5.6

I have `GET` parameter which I want to pass to redirect function.

```
Route::get('/about', function () {
   //I want to add param to this redirect function
   return redirect('/en/about');
});
```

if the route looks like `/about?param=123` after redirect the `param`  will be lost. is there way to add parameter to redirect method? as I see this function doesn't include input parameters. the parameter is optional, so it may not be provided. maybe there's way to override this function? or some other solution? all suggestions will be appreciated

**UPDATE**

is it possible to override the `redirect()` method ? I think in my case it will be the best solution

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have to get the parameter in the URL and pass it to redirect method in an array

```
Route::get('/about/{param}', function () {
   return \Redirect::route('/en/about', ['param'=>$param])
});
```

without having to use named route

```
Route::get('/about/{param}', function () {
   return redirect('/en/about', ['param'=>$param])
});
```

For optional parameter

```
Route::get('/about/{param?}', function ($param = 'my param') {
   return redirect('/en/about', ['param'=>$param])
});
```

Comment: thanks for that, but in this case I have to create named route at first

Comment: for some reasons it doesnt see the parameter. I added it like `/about/{param?}, function($param=null)` because its optional, but I cannot get value

Comment: i have update the answer.  Have you tried that route with and without passing a parameter?

Comment: not sure if it something to with version but I need the parameter to be passed to the function call. ie `function ($param)`

Answer (score 6):

Yeah, you can [redirect to named routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/redirects#redirecting-named-routes) and pass parameters, like this:

```
return redirect()->route('en.about', ['param' => 123]);
```

Comment: thanks, but again it requires the named route. is there way to do it without creating the named route?

Comment: Not sure, why can't you create a named route? There are many benefits from using them.

Answer (score 5):

just do something like this:

```
 return redirect('/en/about?param='.$param);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to add route name then you can do the same with controller function

```
Route::get('/about/{param}', function () {
   return \Redirect::action('CONTROLLER@FUNCTION',['param'=>$param])
});
```

OR with the helper function

```
return redirect()->action('CONTROLLER@FUNCTION');
```

Comment: thanks, but the issue is that the project which I work with mostly just returns the view, it doesn't call to controllers method

Comment: but for redirect, you need to register that route

Answer (score 2):

Its best to do it this way in your case:

```
return redirect(route("en.about")."?param=123");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Route::get('/about', function () {
   //I want to add param to this redirect function
   return redirect()->to(url('/en/about',['param' => 'Pram vakue', 'param2' => $param]));
});
```

If you use a `route()` then you have to create a named route.

Hope this helps

Comment: it fails, `method url does not exist` . maybe it was in older laravel's version

Comment: @devnullΨ have a look at the updated answer I had a typo