# laravel 7 redirect to external url with GET parameters

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Is there any elegant way to redirect to an external url with parameters in laravel?

I'm using this code:

```
$redirect = redirect(config('app.paypal.url') .'?'. http_build_query([
    'charset'       => 'utf-8',
    'paymentaction' => 'sale',
    'no_note'       => 1,
    ...
]));
```

but would prefer to use something like this (it doesn't work because the route is not defined):

```
$redirect = redirect(route(config('app.paypal.url'), [
    'charset'       => 'utf-8',
    'paymentaction' => 'sale',
    'no_note'       => 1,
    ...
]));
```

Comment: Your first solution is already pretty elegant! That being said, I think this is the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50816769/add-get-parameter-to-laravels-redirect-method

Comment: You may want to try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44021662/how-to-create-global-function-that-can-be-accessed-from-any-controller-and-blade

Comment: @onlineThomas thank you, however it doesn't work in my case because the route is external to laravel. exact error is route not defined.

Comment: @ChesterAlan sorry I don't understand the relation with my question. can you explain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
return redirect()->away('https://my.url.com')->with('user',$user)
                                ->with('pass_code',$pass_code)
                                ->with('amount',$amount)
                                ->with('hash_value',$hash_value);
```

Comment: Further, has anyone managed to do a POST request on similar lines? I have been trying much, but haven't had a breakthrough.

Answer (score 0):

Define the url you want to redirect in `$url`

Then just use

```
return Redirect::away($url);
```

Here is the simple example

```
return Redirect::away('http://www.google.com?q=lorem+ipsum');
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#redirecting-external-domains)